# Google Mail not rendering Agenda on Business Account

Tags: php, gmail, google-calendar-api, phpmailer, icalendar

I have two email accounts one that is personal (e.g. `@gmail.com`) and another, that is my business account (e.g. `@businessname.com`). The business account does not render the Google Calendar Agenda inside `gmail` (but my `personal account` does). See screenshots.

This what Google Mail renders on the personal email account (`accountname@gmail.com`)

**Personal Account**

*Web App*

[image: Personal Account Screen Dump]

*Iphone APP*

[image: Personal Account App]

This is what Google Mail renders on business email account (`accountname@businessname.com`)

**Business Account**

*Web App*

[image: Business Account Screen Dump]

*Iphone App*

[image: Business Account App]

I'm unsure why the `business account` is not rendering the "Agenda" while the `personal account` is, only difference between the Emails is the `To Address`.

**Things I have tried**

- I've tried sending the EMAIL, as Calendar Email without HTML Content, but `accountname@businessname.com` renders empty email, while `accountname@gmail.com` renders the Agenda.
- I thought if I supply HTML to Google, that the Google Mail application would properly render the Content. (This assumption is based on information from [Google Email Markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/getting-started))

**MESSAGE SOURCE**

```
Delivered-To: accountname@businessname.com
Received: by 2002:a4f:9f54:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id i81csp9452499ive;
        Wed, 5 Dec 2018 16:14:53 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 2002:a63:dd15:: with SMTP id t21mr21467986pgg.347.1544055053718;
        Wed, 05 Dec 2018 16:10:53 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AFSGD/XUT3bvjcTja8GfwKZ7SKUFypnEmARFt7RSULxpBb/CLNJfpwNpo1Ou0o22/vMQxIjRt08o
X-Received: by 2002:a63:dd15:: with SMTP id t21mr21467934pgg.347.1544055052676;
        Wed, 05 Dec 2018 16:10:52 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1544055052; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=g0gA17P8IYi7mC7KUCVC1BZRlfUS9BkeJbzg5vfVpbSDuzeE4PAuMMLGN6GjAVhRyZ
         LCCTnKErRcDxm2VgzQXj5QhM8qr39I25BkljSuPQFp6dSTWRXfp1Lpb5cpKpXY/EnZzq
         MLvR/qJ5QR1BQoco347Ir4iHTNV2J2NO8n0psGfGiwbOJnNTyxa/lFwYrAKcPpJkX5U+
         j/QBZKWRe8Uj2hNzXJ5MzMFlysWTeAlISgv803vcldIooSNXMTTWmeymQz9CNmeVBf4W
         MCx4aan+7WChkkPpA80EVYzDytzBCaIiCJDtTgB4EXAKa1djVMSu4LMgTVnkz5TJLz/q
         3lfQ==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=content-transfer-encoding:mime-version:message-id:reply-to:cc:from
         :date:subject:to;
        bh=KHON5Re06c4ZEhNKlVkAPpzyIohovOu1KheQQi2CC+s=;
        b=VsMtDNxz+/9s1WRSvH7GkQCRdoa/Y67uBSFHW0ub5yHGMQ3BGpmUcuBFUqwQeMXkNo
         rZpi21QVHfJhcjIikYEcsZeKMgPuqkh9wud/qyK+ZAs2TZDqt+ByIqp5xuMFquiWs9aC
         KI6/XHoWk8WUBbXCS62Lpz6Ujf1gmOkOJHVRYUQwoA6YgLj+9hSMg38XJHaX3cd9/kc5
         l/4Min0YnMnN0W75zUOymhmdLNTb8ChAOXdN3RIlro7necAbqO09ZGgM9BaN+5yvoPJT
         Ldx0dzoJmo3BeNnwPx9agjBU2FMd/c+R0dxU/BDGlDgWnlUQrl5nTi/8zqX7yVgjiJ2B
         EdvQ==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 43.245.55.172 is neither permitted nor denied by domain of accountname@businessname.com) smtp.mailfrom=accountname@businessname.com
Return-Path: <accountname@businessname.com>
Received: from bigbird.businessname.com ([43.245.55.172])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id p17si21592981pfk.275.2018.12.05.16.10.51
        for <accountname@businessname.com>;
        Wed, 05 Dec 2018 16:10:52 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 43.245.55.172 is neither permitted nor denied by domain of accountname@businessname.com) client-ip=43.245.55.172;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 43.245.55.172 is neither permitted nor denied by domain of accountname@businessname.com) smtp.mailfrom=accountname@businessname.com
Received: by bigbird.businessname.com (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id B10B19ACA6; Thu,  6 Dec 2018 13:10:50 +1300 (NZDT)
To: Killrawr <accountname@gmail.com>
Subject: Google Business Event Test
Date: Thu, 6 Dec 2018 13:10:50 +1300
From: Killrawr <accountname@businessname.com>
Cc: Killrawr <accountname@businessname.com>
Reply-To: Killrawr <accountname@businessname.com>
Message-ID: <34a78c17956a92dcb3b373d5e5232d27@www.businessname.com>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.22 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="b1_34a78c17956a92dcb3b373d5e5232d27"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--b1_34a78c17956a92dcb3b373d5e5232d27
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b2_34a78c17956a92dcb3b373d5e5232d27"

--b2_34a78c17956a92dcb3b373d5e5232d27
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

Attendee(s):
Killrawr, KillrawrEvent For:
KillrawrCalendar Reference:

5c08690aab8b0


Event:

Google Business Event Test
Description:
Event DescripionWhen:

Dec 06th 2018 12:12 am
End:

Dec 06th 2018 01:13 am
Location:


Event Location




This email was automatically generated 2018-12-06T13:10:50+13:00


--b2_34a78c17956a92dcb3b373d5e5232d27
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Business Event Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8;" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"EventReservation","reservationNumber":"5c08690aab8b0","underName":{"@type":"Person","name":"Killrawr"},"reservationFor":{"@type":"Event","name":"Google Business Event Test","startDate":"2018-12-06T01:13:00+00:00","endDate":"2018-12-06T00:12:00+00:00","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Event Location"}}}
</script>
<div class='attendee_booking_details' itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation" >
<h4></h4>
<strong>Attendee(s):</strong>
<a href="mailto:accountname@gmail.com" title="accountname@gmail.com" >Killrawr</a>, <a href="mailto:accountname@businessname.com" title="accountname@businessname.com" >Killrawr</a><br/><strong>Event For:</strong>
<span itemprop="underName" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" ><span itemprop="name" >Killrawr</span></span><br/><strong>Calendar Reference:</strong>
<span itemprop="reservationNumber" >
5c08690aab8b0
</span>
<div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
<strong>Event:</strong>
<span itemprop="name" >
Google Business Event Test
</span><br/><strong>Description:</strong>
Event Descripion<br/><strong>When:</strong>
<span itemprop="startDate" datetime="2018-12-06T00:12:00+00:00" >
Dec 06th 2018 12:12 am
</span><br/><strong>End:</strong>
<span itemprop="endDate" datetime="2018-12-06T01:13:00+00:00" >
Dec 06th 2018 01:13 am
</span><br/><strong>Location:</strong>
<span itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" >
<span itemprop="name" >
Event Location
</span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<i>This email was automatically generated 2018-12-06T13:10:50+13:00</i>
</body>
</html>



--b2_34a78c17956a92dcb3b373d5e5232d27--

--b1_34a78c17956a92dcb3b373d5e5232d27
Content-Type: text/calendar; name="invite.ics"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=invite.ics

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 14.0 MIMEDIR//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:NZDT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0545
TZOFFSETTO:+0545
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:5c08690aab8b0
ORGANIZER;CN="Killrawr":MAILTO:accountname@businessname.com
ATTENDEE;CN="Killrawr";RSVP=FALSE:mailto:accountname@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;CN="Killrawr";RSVP=FALSE:mailto:accountname@businessname.com
LOCATION:Event Location
DTSTAMP:20181206T001050Z
CLASS:PUBLIC
DTSTART:20181206T001200Z
DTEND:20181206T011300Z
SUMMARY:Google Business Event Test
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:TENTATIVE
DESCRIPTION:Event Descripion
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-APPTLASTSEQUENCE:1
X-MS-OLK-AUTOSTARTCHECK:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
X-MS-OLK-SENDER;CN="Killrawr":MAILTO:accountname@businessname.com
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<p>Event Descripion</p>
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
REPEAT:1
DURATION:PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Event Descripion
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR


--b1_34a78c17956a92dcb3b373d5e5232d27--
```

**CALENDAR ONLY**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 14.0 MIMEDIR//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:NZDT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0545
TZOFFSETTO:+0545
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:5c08690aab8b0
ORGANIZER;CN="Killrawr":MAILTO:accountname@businessname.com
ATTENDEE;CN="Killrawr";RSVP=FALSE:mailto:accountname@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;CN="Killrawr";RSVP=FALSE:mailto:accountname@businessname.com
LOCATION:Event Location
DTSTAMP:20181206T001050Z
CLASS:PUBLIC
DTSTART:20181206T001200Z
DTEND:20181206T011300Z
SUMMARY:Google Business Event Test
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:TENTATIVE
DESCRIPTION:Event Descripion
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-APPTLASTSEQUENCE:1
X-MS-OLK-AUTOSTARTCHECK:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
X-MS-OLK-SENDER;CN="Killrawr":MAILTO:accountname@businessname.com
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<p>Event Descripion</p>
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
REPEAT:1
DURATION:PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Event Descripion
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**JSON ONLY**

```
{
    "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org",
    "@type": "EventReservation",
    "reservationNumber": "5c08690aab8b0",
    "underName": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Killrawr"
    },
    "reservationFor": {
        "@type": "Event",
        "name": "Google Business Event Test",
        "startDate": "2018-12-06T01:13:00+00:00",
        "endDate": "2018-12-06T00:12:00+00:00",
        "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Event Location"
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML ONLY**

```
<div class='attendee_booking_details' itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation" >
   <h4></h4>
   <strong>Attendee(s):</strong>
   <a href="mailto:accountname@gmail.com" title="accountname@gmail.com" >Killrawr</a>, <a href="mailto:accountname@businessname.com" title="accountname@businessname.com" >Killrawr</a><br/><strong>Event For:</strong>
   <span itemprop="underName" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" ><span itemprop="name" >Killrawr</span></span><br/><strong>Calendar Reference:</strong>
   <span itemprop="reservationNumber" >
   5c08690aab8b0
   </span>
   <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
      <strong>Event:</strong>
      <span itemprop="name" >
      Google Business Event Test
      </span><br/><strong>Description:</strong>
      Event Descripion<br/><strong>When:</strong>
      <span itemprop="startDate" datetime="2018-12-06T00:12:00+00:00" >
      Dec 06th 2018 12:12 am
      </span><br/><strong>End:</strong>
      <span itemprop="endDate" datetime="2018-12-06T01:13:00+00:00" >
      Dec 06th 2018 01:13 am
      </span><br/><strong>Location:</strong>
      <span itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" >
      <span itemprop="name" >
      Event Location
      </span>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
<i>This email was automatically generated 2018-12-06T13:10:50+13:00</i>
```

Comment: I think this is a limitation of gsuite - there are quite a few things that it lacks relative to personal gmail accounts.

Comment: sounds like a settings issue you may want to consider cross posting this to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DalmTo how would I cross post?

Comment: Just a wild guess, Is Google Calendar enabled and also there is a setting in Google Calendar to turn on the "Events from Gmail". Read more https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6084018?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Events from Gmail is already enabled :(

Comment: If your business is paying Google for G Suite email, you should ask them for support.

Comment: @ewindes Thanks I just saw this comment, I'll ask about this next time I talk to my boss.